# ProgrammingError: column cannot be cast automatically to type double precision

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm trying to migrate my Django project from using sqlite3 to using PostgreSQL. I've created the database for the project, but when I try to run `syncdb`, I get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "partial_value" cannot be cast automatically to type double precision
HINT: Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
```

The column is defined like this in the model:

```
partial_value = models.FloatField()
```

I tried searching for similar questions, but they seemed to be more about replacing field types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason to why the field was applied as `character varying` in the first place. It turns out there was a migration file that defined it that way. The error was fixed by removing the migration file and running `manage.py syncdb`.

Comment: see also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30948392/django-1-8-migration-unable-to-cast-column-id-to-integer if you need a less specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

You needs to update the type of column for 'partial_value' column. Place name of table in following code for `table_name`

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN partial_value TYPE double precision USING (trim(partial_value)::double precision);
```

Comment: Could you explain why the error happens in the first place? I checked the type of the column and it was of type 'character varying' instead of double precision.

Comment: As you said the earlier column type was character , but now it seems it is float type, so the data type of the partial_value is changed by dajngo, But that change is not reflected into the database, that's why error is coming.

Comment: No, the column type has always been FloatField in Django. The type in PostgreSQL database was 'character varying'. This is the thing I'm wondering: why does the FloatField convert to 'character varying' ?